# @Transactional default is used inside @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)

Tags: spring, database, transactions, spring-transactions

In the current code `@Transactional` with default propagation is called inside a public method with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`. I am seeing some lag in db commits as per the timestamp matching. ( not always but multiple data points ) can you please help?

Is it because the transactional block for `Propagation.REQUIRED` is using the existing transactional block for `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` and db commits will happen after the parent method returns?

Is this an issue of incorrect nesting of transactions?

Comment: Your description isn't very clear, please show some code.